# which slices form a P Frame or B Frame

Tags: h.264, video-processing, mpeg2-ts

In a H.264 bit stream, how can I find which p-slices/b-slices form which frame? Does the **frame_num** help anyway? Also in my source file(.264 file), **frame_num** field values are inconsistent, i.e, in first slice it is 10, later it becomes 5 like that. Is it okay? Should I use p-slices exactly in that order to make frames?

Answer (score 1):

PArse the slice header. That will tell you what macroblocks are encoded into the slice. Once all macroblobs are accounted for, you are at the end of the frame. You can get the macroblock per frame number by parsing the SPS.